# How to get the cipher signature after SSL handshake?

Tags: c, openssl

I'm making a DTLS client-server program with openssl. The program works fine, but I can't find a way to get the cipher signature after SSL handshake.

By after SSL handshake, I mean in the client side, after:

```
if (SSL_connect(ssl) <= 0)
{
    //error handling 
}
```

In the server side, after:

```
do 
{
    ret = SSL_accept(ssl);
} while (ret == 0);
```

I can see the actual cipher signature is `sha256WithRSAEncryption` from the captured DTLS packets, but how to get this information from openssl?

Note that even though I'm using DTLS protocol, the code is almost the same as TLS/SSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cipher algorithm used is stored in a certificate. So when you have a certificate (x509), the type of cipher algorithm can be extracted. Numeric version only:

```
X509_get_signature_type(client_cert)
```

To get human readable string, convert the return value of the previous function with this:

```
OBJ_nid2ln(X509_get_signature_type(client_cert))
```

Comment: When I use this, I always get `undefined`. Anyway, `OBJ_obj2nid(cert->sig_alg->algorithm)` gives me the correct result.